# Android app privacy policy

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

I plan to include GCM into my app and now I don't know if it needs to be in the privacy policy. And where can I get a good privacy policy for an app for the play store? Are there any privacy policy creators or something like this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of a privacy policy, not programming. Please consult with a qualified attorney for your concerns about privacy policies.

Comment: Although this question is off- topic but targets indie-developers who dont have a team of lawyers or such resources, so should be solved here and not closed, I an reopening and ask others to vote for the same

Comment: It is a programming cycle question, so it deserves an answer since probably I wasn't the only one needlessly spending time on 'trivial' things like this: here is some boilerplate: https://gist.github.com/alphamu/c42f6c3fce530ca5e804e672fed70d78 which seems to originate from privacypolicytemplate.net — I wouldn't call it ready-to-use, some bits didn't sound right to me and needed a bit of editing, but otherwise it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 6):

Yoy may take privacy policy of any app in Google Play and convert it to fit your needs.

Comment: This is a very bad advice and should NOT be followed. Copy-paste is absolutely NOT a good idea, as privacy policies need to be tailored and customised according to the data handling of YOUR SPECIFIC app.

Answer (score -2):

These off-topic questions tend to be closed after a while, let's try to get your questions answered anyway:

First I would advise you to read some general guidance on the topic, like the one presented by the Attorney General of California called [Privacy on the Go](http://oag.ca.gov/sites/all/files/pdfs/privacy/privacy_on_the_go.pdf). When you're knowledgeable about the topic you might as well try privacy policy generators and see whether they suit your particular case.

I'm part of [iubenda](https://www.iubenda.com/blog/2013/06/10/the-need-for-privacy-policies-in-mobile-apps-an-overview/), a team with a mix developers/designers/lawyers who are building tools exactly for this use case: apps and websites. You can [find the generator for mobile apps here](http://iubenda.com/en/mobile). *iubenda's mobile privacy policy is on a paid only plan currently, but you can always test drive the generator for your website's policy*.

Now as a general caveat let me advise against copying off of other sites or apps (as suggested by the answer before me). You *may* infringe copyright and import several other problems. Who tells you that the pp/terms you decided to be fit for copy aren't fundamentally flawed themselves?

Today there's great guidance out there, and great help like the one provided by iubenda. Take advantage of it!

**edit** regarding the comment pointing out that iubenda is paid: that's right and I've added a sentence regarding this to the answer. One of the advantages of a paid policy is that you get to ask questions and request improvements any time :)

Comment: I have tried iubenda today. It does not allow you to add services as admob unless you pay. Also it does not allow you to generate an application privacy policy unless you pay. I'll keep searching for something free.

Comment: @Aebsubis have you found any?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian I have not found an interesting privacy policy generator for apps and now it is mandatory according to the user data policy of Google Play. I am still interested in a generator. I think it would be very handy. In the meantime I am researching privacy policies that are already out there and collecting the bits that are relevant for my app.

Comment: @Simon Aesubis already said he wants a free service instead of iubenda... then you go an plug iubenda. Logical ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere the question does NOT specifically ask for a free service, which you seem to instead imply. You may consider editing your comment to reflect the truth. The fact that an answer is downvoted because the proposed solution is not free of charge, given that the question didn't specifically ask for something free, honestly leaves me perplexed.